# Time machine working but cant restore from backups?

Tags: time-machine

I have a Time Machine backup from earlier today. When I enter Time Machine it shows me the backup and appears to work fine. However The option to restore is greyed out and unavailable.

Ive made a change to a folder since then so there is a change to restore from. I haven't excluded any files to be backed up.

Im having the same issue on 2 laptops. One running 10.9.5 and one running 10.10. Im using different hard drives for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If worst comes to worst, you can just dig down the Time Machine drive hierarchy -

'Time Machine Drive' > Backups.backupdb > 'computer name' > Latest > then you get the same hierarchy as your backed up drives.
You can then just do a regular copy back to any other partition.

If Latest doesn't contain the files you need, then search could find them, or you could dig back down the dated backups

Answer (score 0):

Im able to load a snapshot from timemachine by restoring and holding down the apple and R key. Then you get different rebooting options.

Answer (score -1):

reboot> press Commmand and R together until apple logo shows up and release the buttons > in  OSX Utilities windows ( if you don't see it popup, try to reboot again) Choose Restore from Time machine.  It will not grayout in here.